# how to scroll search cell by clicking arrow down and arrow up buttons android recyclerview like whatsapp

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-recyclerview

i want to scroll recycler-view by clicking arrow up and arrow down keys if there is multiple search keys in the list as shown in the image two buttons right side of the searchview i have 5 search keys it might be more so when i press up or down button i have to go that particular search like whatsapp

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
myRecyclerview.scrollToPosition(position);
```

Give your recycler position which you want to scroll